# Debugging Go with tags in Visual Studio Code and Delve debugger

Tags: debugging, go, visual-studio-code

**Answer:**
Based on putus answer, I figured out the following configuration to build and debug with one click

At first you need to add a task to build the binary with the respective tags.

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "command": "bash",
  "isShellCommand": true,
  "args": [""],
  "showOutput": "always",
  "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "buildBinWithTag",
            "command": "go",
            "args": ["build", "-o", "BinaryName", "-tags", "THISISATAG"],
            "isShellCommand": true            
        }       
    ]
}
```

This task should be executed before the debugger launches.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "DebugBinWithTag",    //added config
      "type": "go",
      "request": "launch",
      "mode": "exec",
      "remotePath": "",
      "port": 2345,
      "host": "127.0.0.1",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/BinaryName",
      "env": {},
      "args": [],
      "showLog": true,
      "preLaunchTask": "buildBinWithTag"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Original question**:I'm using build tags for compiling different versions of a Go program and I compile it with "go build -tags THISISAFLAG"

```
//+build THISISAFLAG

package main
```

This works perfectly. But is there a way to tell the debugger to use these flags. I've tried to use a launch configuration like the following, but it didn't work.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch",
      "type": "go",
      "request": "launch",
      "mode": "debug",
      "remotePath": "",
      "port": 2345,
      "host": "127.0.0.1",
      "program": "${fileDirname}",
      "env": {},
      "args": ["-flags THISISAFLAG"],
      "showLog": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach pre-built binary to debugger.

1. Build the application from command line, e.g. `go build -o myapp.exe -tags THISISAFLAG`
2. Add configuration `Launch Exe` to `launch.json`

   ```
   {
     "version": "0.2.0",
     "configurations": [
       {
         "name": "Launch Debug",  //existing config
         "type": "go",
         "request": "launch",
         "mode": "debug",
         "remotePath": "",
         "port": 2345,
         "host": "127.0.0.1",
         "program": "${fileDirname}",
         "env": {},
         "args": [],
         "showLog": true
       },
       {
         "name": "Launch EXE",    //added config
         "type": "go",
         "request": "launch",
         "mode": "exec",
         "remotePath": "",
         "port": 2345,
         "host": "127.0.0.1",
         "program": "${workspaceRoot}/myapp.exe",
         "env": {},
         "args": [],
         "showLog": true
       }
     ]
   }
   ```

**Note:**

Due to compiler optimization and [this issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14319), some variables may not being displayed or displayed with different name during debug session (see below). In the future, you may add `-gcflags='-N -l'` when building the application to disable compiler optimization.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The [Visual Studio Code Go plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go) now supports a `launch.json` key called `buildFlags` that allows you to specify the build tags with a corresponding value of `"-tags Tag"`.  (There appears to be [a bug disallowing multiple tags](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/issues/1901).).

Relevant [excerpt from the plugin Wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/wiki/Debugging-Go-code-using-VS-Code):

> If your build needs build tags (e.g. go build -tags whatever_tag), then add the parameter buildFlags with the content "-tags whatever_tag".

If you have different build configurations each requiring their own build tag, you can create separate launch configurations for each.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my test configurations:

```
{
  "name": "Delve: Test",
  "type": "go",
  "request": "launch",
  "mode": "test",
  "buildFlags": "-tags 'unit_tests integration_tests all_tests'",
  "program": "${file}",
  "showLog": true
}
```

1. It will keep erroring out unless the tags don't exist in the selected file.
2. You may want to change `"${file}"` to `"${fileDirname}"` depending on your usecase, if you are using the latter, at least one of the files should have the mentioned tag.